# Using YQL to get list of exchange markets

Tags: yql

I do not want to query for just some stock quote but I want to use YQL to fetch a list of stock quotes which one can trade at a specific exchange market. I searched the list of tables at the YQL console, but I can not find what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is not exposed through YQL, nor through Yahoo! Finance. If you found such a public list or database on the internet, one could write a YQL table to fetch from the source.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but I've seen it now so it can be useful for others.

You can check the list of exchange markets handled by yahoo finance at this address

http://finance.yahoo.com/exchanges

You can easily parse the page in order to retrieve data.